# How to bind Ctrl+/ in python tkinter?

Tags: python, key-bindings

```
<Control-Shift-Key-0>
<Control-Key-plus>
```

works but

```
<Control-Key-/>
```

doesn't.

I am unable to bind <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> in python. Is there any documentation of all the possible keys?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `<Control-slash>`:

```
def quit(event):
    print "you pressed control-forwardslash"
    root.quit()

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Control-slash>', quit)      # forward-slash
# root.bind('<Control-backslash>', quit)  # backslash
root.mainloop()
```

---

I don't have a link to a complete list of these event names. Here is a partial list I've collected:

```
| event                 | name                  |
| Ctrl-c                | Control-c             |
| Ctrl-/                | Control-slash         |
| Ctrl-\                | Control-backslash     |
| Ctrl+(Mouse Button-1) | Control-1             |
| Ctrl-1                | Control-Key-1         |
| Enter key             | Return                |
|                       | Button-1              |
|                       | ButtonRelease-1       |
|                       | Home                  |
|                       | Up, Down, Left, Right |
|                       | Configure             |
| window exposed        | Expose                |
| mouse enters widget   | Enter                 |
| mouse leaves widget   | Leave                 |
|                       | Key                   |
|                       | Tab                   |
|                       | space                 |
|                       | BackSpace             |
|                       | KeyRelease-BackSpace  |
| any key release       | KeyRelease            |
| escape                | Escape                |
|                       | F1                    |
|                       | Alt-h                 |
```

Comment: Then how to add backward-slash as binding?

Comment: Use `<Control-backslash>`.

Comment: @unutbu I realised that the problem is something else. Command+Down triggers within tkinter just the Down arrow, however using Command+Down selects the box below instead of the text area which makes it possible to select items from a list. So I guess I need to find out how to select that area without the command key. Any ideas?

Comment: @Joop: I'm not sure but I think the answer is to subclass the widget and override the `Command+Down` binding. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm (search for the word "override").

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did not manage to fix it yet. If you have by any chance time to look at it, I tried to clearly formulate my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42181333/3972558

Comment: Apparently `<alt-k>` is not correct, and neither is `Alt-k`. It must be exactly `<Alt-k>` to control the Alt-K keystroke. Just wow... I hadn't stumble upon the correct arrangement until I read this post.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a list of all the tk keysysm codes:
https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/keysyms.htm

The two I was looking for was `<Win_L>` and `<Win_R>`.

Comment: This is a very useful resource, used it to find how to bind the release of a Ctrl button.