# Control+Number Tkinter binding

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter

I want to bind a <kbd>Control+1</kbd> sequence to a window. `widget.bind("<Control-1>", lambda event: someFunction(event))` binds <kbd>Control + Left Mouse Click</kbd>. This is the snippet of my code that will use this:

```
self.master.bind("<Control-1>", lambda event: self.allTypeButtons[1].invoke())
self.master.bind("<Control-2>", lambda event: self.allTypeButtons[2].invoke())
self.master.bind("<Control-3>", lambda event: self.allTypeButtons[3].invoke())
# self.allTypeButtons is a dictionary with Radiobuttons as its values
```

I also tried `self.master.bind("<Control>-1", lambda event: self.allTypeButtons[1].invoke())`, but this gives me: `_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Control"`.

Also, `self.master.bind("Control-1", lambda event: self.allTypeButtons[1].invoke())` and then pressing <kbd>Control+1</kbd> doesn't invoke the event.

I know that `widget.bind("1", lambda event: someFunction(event))` binds <kbd>1</kbd>,  `widget.bind("<1>", lambda event: someFunction(event))` binds <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd>, and `widget.bind("<Control-h>", lambda event: someFunction(event))` binds <kbd>Control+h</kbd>, but how can I incorporate <kbd>Control+1</kbd>? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The event name is `<Control-Key-1>`.

```
import Tkinter as tk
def quit(event):
    print("You pressed Control-Key-1")
    root.quit()

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Control-Key-1>', quit)
root.mainloop()
```

I've posted a [partial table of event names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16082243/190597) here.