# Python Tkinter Keypress Special Cases

Tags: python, tkinter, escaping

I was trying to bind `<Control-1>` to call a function and after some confusion, I realized that this meant `<Control-Button1>` and not like `<Control-9>`. What is the complete list of all the special cases, like `-` --> `<minus>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this - maybe you find some special cases:

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/keysyms.htm

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/key-names.html

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-modifiers.html

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16082411/1832058