# Tkinter: Bind key to select next window and scroll through that window's list

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to adapt this working example from [here](https://gist.github.com/uroshekic/11078820) that used tkinter to give auto-completion results based on input of the user. When I run the program and fill in some characters, e.g. `'a'`, I want to automatically have the first entry of the list selected and use my down arrow to scroll further down that list. I have not managed to adapt it to achieve this as no matter what key-bindings I try, it does not focus on the auto-completion result list.

The only way I can actually scroll down with the arrow keys is by using Command+Down on my computer. I have no idea what this is doing internally as even binding Command+Down in code does not give the same behaviour (gives a ? sign in text field). Therefore, my question is: how can you bind the down arrow to scroll through the auto-complete list (Listbox)?

I hope you can help me out on this.

Comment: Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you but it's already one of the most minimalistic examples possible.